# "Restore your search settings?"

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I occasionally restart Firefox using the "Restart Normally" button on the `about:profiles` page and up until now it has restarted without incident.

But today, once Firefox restarted, a new tab was opened asking me if I'd like to restore my search to Bing.

[image]

The page address was `file:///C:/ProgramData/SearchRestore/restore.htm`.  When I installed Firefox I set my default search engine to Google.  I never use Bing.  I am thinking either Microsoft is really overstepping boundaries with Windows aggressively trying to get users to switch to Bing, or that this is the result of malware.  It is probably the former, but my *Google* search did not turn up anything concrete.  Is anyone familiar with this behaviour and where it originates from?

EDIT: Apparently this page is an imitation of an actual Firefox page reachable at address `about:searchreset`. [source](https://techdows.com/2016/08/firefox-search-reset-feature.html)

Comment: My google-fu (do people still say that?) seems to be a little sharper today, and I found [this helpful post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1241130) by a user who also encountered this dubious page.  I think the trigger was that, prior to restarting Firefox, I blew away over six months of browsing history.  I discovered a legacy FF extension "Mozilla Partner Defaults", which perhaps was the culprit.

Comment: So entirely Mozilla overstepping not Microsoft?

Comment: @Ramhound Possibly. It remains to be seen. I'm still trying to verify this extension was legit.  But perhaps it was a part of some software bundling, in which case joint effort? ;) But why would FF need an extension to simulate an apparent built-in feature?

Comment: It probably doesn’t and might be malicious .  *SearchRestore* doesn’t sound legitimate

Comment: This just happened to me too. Strangely, the last modified date on the `SearchRestore` directory and the files in it is the time I turned my computer on.